A confusion with Fourier Transform. Two approaches yields two different solutions.
I had a problem in class about Signals and Systems. Basically, problem is this.
Find the Fourier Transform of a signal $$x(t) = e^{-a|t|}, a > 0$$
I approached this problem like this,
$$X(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-a|t|}e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
Since, the signal is symmetric about Y-axis,
$$X(j\omega) = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at}e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
$$ = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(a+j\omega)t}dt$$
$$=2\mathscr{L}{[1]}|_{s=a+j\omega}$$
$$=\frac{2}{a+j\omega}$$
But, in book "Signals & Systems" the approach was different and $X(j\omega)$ was real.
Book goes like this,
$$X(j\omega) = \int_{-\infty }^{\infty} e^{-a|t|}e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
$$ = \int_{-\infty }^{0} e^{at}e^{-j\omega t}dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at}e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{a-j\omega} + \frac{1}{a+j\omega}$$
$$=\frac{2a}{a^2 + \omega^2}$$
I understood the approach of the book but I still didn't understand why my approach was wrong. Can't I apply that symmetry property of integrals when complex numbers/variables are involved?

$e^{-a|t|}$ is indeed an even function (i.e. symmetric with respect to the $y$-axis), but $e^{-j\omega t}$ isn't, so that the integrand is not even and $\int_{-\infty }^\infty e^{-a|t|}e^{-j\omega t} \mathrm{d}t \neq 2\int_0^\infty e^{-a|t|}e^{-j\omega t} \mathrm{d}t$.

It is because $e^{-j\omega t}$ is not symmetric about the Y axis, that your first method is incorrect and yields the wrong answer.

@Abezhiko understood, are there properties of symmetry for complex integrals too? If yes, where can I read them?
